# Filter SQL GROUP by a filter that is not in GROUP

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, .net-core

Im working on a stream service like app based on C# NET.Core. Im "pinging" the server from client every minute and then create a new SQL entry with time and ID of this viewer.

Here is a example of 5 minutes of view:

```
StreamViewerId | TrackDate
             1 | 2020-09-25 05:05:00
             1 | 2020-09-25 05:06:00
             1 | 2020-09-25 05:07:00
             1 | 2020-09-25 05:08:00
             1 | 2020-09-25 05:09:00
             1 | 2020-09-25 05:10:00
             ...
```

I need to make a "chart bars" based on that data and i cant make the graphic with 1 minute as xAxis, so i trying to make each graphic point at least 5 minutes or more. The problem is that if i just use below query, all the viewers are been multiplicated x5, because they ping the server every minute, so there ill be 5 rows in a group:

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(LiveStreamViewerId) [Count], 
   dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,TrackDate)/5)*5,0) [TrackDate] 
   FROM LiveStreamViewerTracks 
   WHERE LiveStreamId = 1
GROUP BY dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,TrackDate)/5)*5,0)
```

Im actually getting this result:

```
Count | TrackDate
    5 | 2020-09-25 05:05:00
    ...
```

And i want to consider this viewer as only one register (because is only one viewer, not 5). Below is expected result:

```
Count | TrackDate
    1 | 2020-09-25 05:05:00
```

I can't use neither SQL partition, because i cant group by viewerid because im already grouping by datetime, so i cant filter it. Someone can help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Comment: @jarlh Editted it, thanks for example!

Comment: Don't you want 2020-09-25 05:10:00 returned too? I'd consider that timestamp as a new 5 minute period.

Comment: @jarlh If i do i will ned to desconsider 2020-09-25 05:05:00 then, right? Because this logic will turn this timestamp to previous group, making the same number in the range, right?

Comment: So the next period is 05:10:01 - 05:15:01, and then 05:15:02 - 05:20:02, and 05:20:03 - 05:25:03 etc?

Comment: Why count distinct when it always will be 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of COUNT(LiveStreamViewerID), you can use [COUNT(DISTINCT LiveStreamViewerID)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-count-and-distinct) which removes duplicates.

Comment: OH MY GOD! I cant believe thats possible. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks! But please give it a shot to ensure it does what you want it to do.

Comment: I checked, it really does what i need. Also i editted my question before your answer, and thats exactly what i needed. Thank you!

Comment: OP's problem? @jarlh

Comment: OP = The person who asked the question.

Comment: @jarlh You're like a Stack Oraculum, just learned  OP = Original Poster. Thanks!

Comment: I agree that this is probably not the optimal approach. In the future, when there are hundreds of thousands of rows, I think it would be likely that this part will need to be rewritten to get rid of the horrible-looking group by (as it forces a full table/index scan). But the optimal solution from there could be any number of things (windowed functions, indexing, pre-calculation, etc). On the other hand, this solution is simple, and if it works, lets the OP continue on to other things... and find other questions like "what happens when my server is rebooting so I have no data for 10 minutes?"

Comment: @seanb Yeah, i think about it, but had to made this way temporary... anyway, is there any sugestion of how i can achieve this with no performance issues? I mean, how can i store how long everybody stay watching, etc? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: When you get a history of data (days/months/years) you will need a different approach. There are multiple. As the data is historical/will never change, I would pre-calculate the data and store it in a separate table. Treat your current table as just data storage table. For reporting have the data already processed and saved separately.I suggest learning about INDEXes and SARGability and recommend Brent Ozar's videos [How to think like an SQL Server engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fERXOywBhlA&t=324s) and [When SARGability matters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uiv82g1gatE&t=843s)