# Manage live stream viewer huge log

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, nosql

I've developped an .NET CORE application for Live Stream, witch has a lot of funcionalities. One of those, is to show to our clients how many people was watching in every 5 minute interval.

By now, im saving on a SQL Server database, a log for each viewer with `ViewerID` and `TimeStamp` in a 5 minutes interval. It seem's to be a bad approach, since in first couple days, i've reached 100k rows in that table. I need that data, because we have a "Time Peek Chart", that shows how many people and who was watching in a 5 minutes interval.

Anyways, do anyone have a suggestion of how can i handle this? I was thinking about a .txt file with the same data, but it also seems that I/O of the server can be a problem...
Also o though about a NoSQL database, maybe use a existing MongoDB AaS, like scalegrid.io or mlab.com.

Can someone help me with this, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A periodic process that groups and counts into default 5 minute intervals and jettisons the raw data, leaving you with a table that grows by 288 rows a day? BTW "design my program for me" is off topic for stack overflow so you're gonna have to do some thinking on this and come up with something yourself I'm afraid. My first step would be "what data do I need in order to answer question X?" and not store any more than I need. I don't need a table full of "it's 00:00 and viewer X is still connected" times 1000 different X, "it's 00:05 and viewer X is still connected"..

Comment: A "it's 00:05 and 1000 people are connected" would be fine. If however, you know that next week the boss is gonna start asking for analysis on streaming habits, "you're gonna need a bigger disk" :) (still don't need a 5 minutely polled list of all connected people though; just store the start and stop time)

Comment: Thanks for the points @CaiusJard ! Thought this question was reasonable to post on StackOverflow. Appreciate your answer and gonna considerate it to refactor the way its stored... i have another questions but dont think you will be happy to answer "design my program for me" :P. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume this is related to one of your previous questions [Filter SQL GROUP by a filter that is not in GROUP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060109/filter-sql-group-by-a-filter-that-is-not-in-group) and an expansion of the question in comments 'how to make this better'.

This answer below is definitely not the only way to do this - but I think it's a good start.

As you're using SQL Server for the initial data storage (minute-by-minute) I would suggest continuing to use SQL Server for the next stage of data storage. I think you'd need a compelling argument to use something else for the next stage, as you then need to maintain both of them (e.g., keeping software up-to-date, backups, etc), as well as having all the fun of transferring data properly between the two pieces of software.

My suggested approach is to keep the most detailed/granular data that you need, but no more.

In the previous question, you were keeping data by the minute, then calculating up to the 5-minute bracket. In this answer I'd summarise (and store) the data for the 5-minute brackets then discard your minute-by-minute data once it has been summarised.

For example, you could have a table called 'StreamViewerHistory' that has the Viewer's ID and a timestamp (much like the original table).

- This only has 1 row per viewer per 5 minute interval. You could make the timestamp field a smalldatetime (as you don't care about seconds) or even have it as an ID value pointing to another table that references each timeframe. I think smalldatetime is easier to start with.
- Depending exactly on how it's used, I would suggest having the Primary Key (or at least the Clustered index) being the timestamp before the ViewerID - this means new rows get added to the end. It also assumes that most queries of data are filtered by timeframes first (e.g., last week's worth of data).
- I would consider having an index on ViewerId then the timestamp, for when people want to view an individual's history.
  e.g.,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StreamViewerHistory](
    [TrackDate] smalldatetime NOT NULL,
    [StreamViewerID] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_StreamViewerHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    [TrackDate] ASC,
    [StreamViewerID] ASC
    )
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_StreamViewerHistory_StreamViewerID] ON [dbo].[StreamViewerHistory]
    (
    [StreamViewerID] ASC,
    [TrackDate] ASC
    )
GO
```

Now, on some sort of interval (either as part of your ping process, or a separate process run regularly) interrogate the data in your source table `LiveStreamViewerTracks`, crunch the data as per the previous question, and save the results in this new table. Then delete the rows from LiveStreamViewerTracks to keep it smaller and usable. Ensure you delete the relevant rows only though (e.g., the ones that have been processed).

The advantage of the above process is that the data in this new table is very usable by SQL Server. Whenever you need a graph (e.g., of the last 14 days) it doesn't need to read the whole table - instead it just starts at the relevant day and only read the relevant rows. Note to make sure your queries are SARGable though e.g.,

```
-- This is SARGable and can use the index
SELECT TrackDate, StreamViewerID
FROM   StreamViewerHistory
WHERE  TrackDate >= '20201001'

-- These are non-SARGable and will read the whole table
SELECT TrackDate, StreamViewerID
FROM   StreamViewerHistory
WHERE  CAST(TrackDate as date) >= '20201001'

SELECT TrackDate, StreamViewerID
FROM   StreamViewerHistory
WHERE  DATEDIFF(day, TrackDate, '20201001') <= 0
```

Typically, if you want counts of users for every 5 minutes within a given timeframe, you'd have something like

```
SELECT TrackDate, COUNT(*) AS NumViewers
FROM   StreamViewerHistory
WHERE  TrackDate >= '20201001 00:00:00' AND TrackDate < '20201002 00:00:00'
GROUP BY TrackDate
```

This should be good enough for quite a while. If your views/etc do slow down a lot, you could consider other things to help e.g., you could also do further calculations/other reporting tables e.g., also have a table with TrackDate and NumViewers - where there's one row per TrackDate. This should be very fast when reporting overall number of users, but will not allow you to drill down to a specific user.

Comment: Thank you very much! You did an awesome answer, cant believe! Your answer did more than just clarify, it teached. Thanksss @seanb